# Need to save data while custom module installation

Tags: module, installation, magento2.2.6, installdata

I need to save some data while custom module installation. I save some static data using **setup/InstallData.php**. I need to process the existing order data and save it into my custom table. Is there any other way to save instead of  **setup/InstallData.php**. Is this good to call controller function inside the **setup/InstallData.php**.

I am using Magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good to call controller function inside the
>   setup/InstallData.php

No, it is not recommended controller call should be from request.

> Is there any other way to save instead of setup/InstallData.php

No, not any because whenever module is installing only InstallData script are run.

But you can create command line file after installing module you can run command and it will import your order data in custom table.